# Executing .exe file in Shiny app with interactive input

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny app that calls an external .exe file. The .exe file requires interactive input during execution. Currently, the .exe file is running in the console, but I want the interface to be within the Shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Run .exe File"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("exeFile", "Choose .exe file"),
      actionButton("runButton", "Run .exe")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  processing <- reactiveVal(FALSE)  # Initialize processing as FALSE
  
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    req(input$exeFile)  # Check if a file is selected
    
    # Get the path of the selected .exe file
    # exe_path <- input$exeFile$datapath
    exe_path <- normalizePath(input$exeFile$datapath)
    
    
    # Set processing to TRUE
    processing(TRUE)
    
    # Run the .exe file
    # Example: Redirecting input from a file
    #result <- system2(command = exe_path, input = "path_to_input_file.txt")
    result <- system2(command = exe_path, input = "1\n")  # Example: Provide "1" as input
    
    # Set processing back to FALSE when done
    processing(FALSE)
    
    # Print the result (you can customize this part)
    cat("Command exit status:", result, "\n")
  })
  
  observe({
    if (processing()) {
      # If processing is TRUE, update the UI accordingly
      shinyjs::disable("runButton")
      shinyjs::disable("exeFile")
    } else {
      # If processing is FALSE, update the UI accordingly
      shinyjs::enable("runButton")
      shinyjs::enable("exeFile")
      
      # Display a message when processing is completed
      output$output_message <- renderText({
        "Processing completed. You can run the .exe file again."
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**The output looks like this :**

```
The scale of the Eco-Hydro V 3.0  Model Application
   ===================================================
   [01] Multi River Basins/Regional Scale             
   [02] Single River Basin Scale                      
   [03] .........                                     
 
   Select the scale level for the model application [1 as default]!:   
   A. Main Program for Hydrotopographic Data Input Processing 
 
   Continue to the model data input processing? [Y/N]!:   
   Multi River Basins/Regional Scale Eco-Hydro V 3.0 Modeling:              
   A.  Main Program for Hydrotopographic Data Input Processing 
 
   1.do you need to convert dem and flow direction data format?(Y/N) 
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit -4, file CONIN$
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
0.exe              004CF919  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Command exit status: 24
```

I want to capture this interactive input within the Shiny app. Specifically, I want to provide input choices such as "1", "Y", etc., based on the prompts generated by the .exe file.

It is looks like this, if we are running the .exe file in local/cmd :
[image]